# Covariance of normal distributed random variables if one variable is squared

Tags: probability, expected-value, covariance, correlation

If I have two correlated normal distributed random variables, i.e. $A \sim N(m_a,\sigma_a^2)$ and $B \sim N(m_b,\sigma_b^2)$, with correlation coefficient $ Corr(A,B) =\rho $, then I know that the $Cov(A,B) = \rho \sigma_a \sigma_b$.

My question: What ist the covariance of $A$ and $B^2$, i.e. $Cov(A,B^2)$ ?
My approach: For simplicity, we can also assume that $B$ is standard normal, i.e. $m_b = 0$ and $\sigma^2_b = 1$. Then we have:
\begin{align}
Cov(A,B^2) &= E\left[(A-m_a)(B^2-E(B^2))  \right] \\
 &= E\left[(A-m_a)(B^2-1)  \right] \\
 &= E[AB^2] - E[A] - m_aE[B^2] + m_a, \hspace{0.5cm} \text{since $E[B^2]=1$} \\
 &= E[AB^2] - m_a - m_a + m_a \\
 &= E[AB^2] - m_a
\end{align}
At this point I don't get further.

Comment: Assuming $(A,B)$ is a bivariate Gaussian, use Cov(A,B) to get $A=a_1Z+a_2B$, $Z$ standard Gaussian independent of $B$, and use expectation of the product is product of expectation for independent variables.